# Redundant column - one to one mapping with composite id

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

This is my model

```
@Entity
public class Picture {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PictureId id;

    ...   
}

@Embeddable
public class PictureId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8285116986358642545L;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "GALLERY_ID") private long galleryId;
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "AUTHOR_ID") private long authorId;
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "ORDINAL_NUMBER") private int ordinalNumber;

    ...   
}

@Entity
public class Gallery {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "REDUNDANT_GALLERY_ID", referencedColumnName = "GALLERY_ID"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "COVER_AUTHOR_ID", referencedColumnName = "AUTHOR_ID"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "COVER_ORDINAL_NUMBER", referencedColumnName = "ORDINAL_NUMBER")
    })
    private Picture cover;

    ...
}
```

I guess specifing `@JoinColums` here is not necessary but I wanted to make it more clear. With this model there is a redundant column created in my `GALLERY` table that mirrors the value of `ID`. I would like to get rid of this column. Field `cover` might be null.

After thinking a lot on this I decided I better move this mapping to the external table. Obviously it didn't solve my problem and it gets even more complicated.

```
@Entity
public class Gallery {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "GALLERY_COVER",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "GALLERY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "REDUNDANT_GALLERY_ID", referencedColumnName = "GALLERY_ID"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_ID", referencedColumnName = "AUTHOR_ID"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "ORDINAL_NUMBER", referencedColumnName = "ORDINAL_NUMBER")
    })
    private Picture cover;
}
```

I was trying to use `@AssociationOverride` and `@AttributeOverride` but I failed. Can you help me with these mappings?

---

Edit: Here is a [repository](https://github.com/sdwsk/composite-mapping) with this model

Comment: You might be able to mark the "redundant" join column read-only: `@JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "GALLERY_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)`

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried that. It complains that ```Mixing insertable and non insertable columns in a property is not allowed```

Comment: In some ways, I think that re-using `Gallery`'s primary key as part of a foreign key to `Picture`'s composite primary key is problematic. There is nothing explicit in the data model that requires `Gallery`'s `cover` to be one of the same `Gallery`'s pictures. It is entirely possible that the `cover` `Picture` could have a different `Gallery` ID in its primary key. In which case, the "redundant" `Gallery` ID is not really redundant.

Comment: You are right. I didn't notice it before. But enforcing cover to be one of the picture from that gallery by reusing ```Gallery```'s ID would be a positive side effect for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget the join table and the redundant column name. It's OK to use the same column name twice in one Entity as long as only one instance of it can be inserted/updated. The `@Column` and `@JoinColumn` annotations let you override the default insertable/updatable values.

```
@Entity
public class Gallery {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            // no new column name here, just specify insertable/updatable
            @JoinColumn(name = "GALLERY_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "COVER_AUTHOR_ID", referencedColumnName = "AUTHOR_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "COVER_ORDINAL_NUMBER", referencedColumnName = "ORDINAL_NUMBER", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private Picture cover;

    ...
}
```

The cleaner approach, however, would be to change the primary key on `Picture` so it doesn't include the `galleryId`. If `authorId` and `ordinalNumber` already specify a unique key, just remove `galleryId` from the join.

Comment: Did you test that? I am getting ```org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Mixing insertable and non insertable columns in a property is not allowed: pl.sdwsk.model.Gallery.cover```. Unfortunately I can not get rid of ```galleryId``` from composite key.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate... looks like you'd have to set all 3 join columns to be `insertable=false, updatable=false`. If you ever need to set them, you'd have to separately define `@Column(name = "COVER_AUTHOR_ID"` like you have for for the Gallery id. If nothing else, this underscores the importance of a clean data model

Comment: Given the fact that I will always need to set the covers it sounds like a mess ;) I'll better leave it off with @JointTable for now.

Comment: The join table is really meant for `ManyToMany` relationships... there's no way to assign a better PK to the `Picture` entity?

Comment: [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html) mentions about one to one relationships as well. Actually I really need this tripple PK model. I am using ```ordinalNumber``` for file naming. Convention for this looks like this: ```{galleryName}/{author}_{ordinalNumber}.{ext}``` and it goes 1:1 with database.

Comment: Just because you *can* doesn't mean you should. Personally, I would use a an auto-generated sequence for the Picture ID and use that alone for your filename. That way if you want to move a picture from one gallery to another, you don't need to change the filename. I also assume that your galleries will have more than one picture, so you could still have a `gallery_id` on the pictures to make that a simple single-column one-to-many relationship from gallery->pictures.

Comment: Are you aware that you want me to leverage your word over oracle's documentation without any provided resource? Even in [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne) there is an example of one to one relashionship mapped by @JoinTable. It's not easy to figure out what you mean by ```The join table is really meant for ManyToMany```. Anyway the cost of reimplementing my filename -> db mappings is way too high to even consider it for such a small thing. I might use sequence but then my filenames would be quite ugly and I want them to be short and meaningful.

Comment: I'm not saying it can't be done. I'm saying that your data model is unnecessarily cumbersome as-is. As it stands, you've created both new table and duplicated column for what could otherwise be a simple join. You're not bound in any way to take my recommendations, but I'm trying to help you arrive at a solution that will reduce data duplication and be easier to maintain.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you meant. I am here to learn and I really appreciate your time. You are right that I created new table and duplicated even more data just for the sake that I can. About maintenance - given my lack of experience I'm figuring those stuff on the go and this is how I ended up with this composite key and I really like it for my [specification](http://piccollector.sdwsk.pl/). I will go back to the @JoinColumn. If no one proposes a solution I'll accept your answer in few days. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I end up rebuilding everything just like you said :) This ordinal number was a bad idea from a maintenance point of view. I choose to use time stamp in my file names. Lesson learned! Thank you again.